Supercell Symmetry with VESTA
I have recently generated a Supercell of TiO2 rutile with VESTA. I have started from the CIF file and then I selected the option "search atoms in the new unit cell and add them as new sites" in order to use the crystal_sg option for the atomic position on Quantum ESPRESSO but the number of atoms in the cell gets lost!
I don't know what could have gone wrong!
Thank you in advance for everything!
Martino
EDIT: I've also tried a calculation with cartesian coordinates, but it gets from D4h to D2h. Also here, I can in principle use cartesian coordinates, but still I get symmetry error!

Hi. Did you find any solution to your problem? If not, could you share your CIF file here as a code block? Sometimes codes fail to find symmetry because of not enough decimal points in the atomic position coordinates.
